# Calling setText on EditText not always change content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am trying to change the value of an editText inside a fragment by calling the `setText` method on the input. But it does not always work :

- sometimes when I change from spinner value the good text is associated to the edittext, but other times it does not change its value
- sometimes on device rotation the text is well updated, other times not
  But in all cases, when logging the new text content into the Logcat, it is the expected string (the new content).

Here the fragment defintion (using kotlinX extention for reffering to widgets)

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import com.loloof64.android.basicchessendgamestrainer.PositionGeneratorValuesHolder
import com.loloof64.android.basicchessendgamestrainer.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_editing_other_pieces_global_constraint.*
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
import java.util.logging.Logger

class OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorFragment : Fragment() {

    private var spinnerPiecesKindValues = listOf<PieceKind>()
    private var lastSpinnerSelectedItem : PieceKind? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editing_other_pieces_global_constraint, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {




 generator_editor_spinner_other_piece_global_constraint.
 onItemSelectedListener =

OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorSpinnerSelectionListener(this)





 generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
 onFocusChangeListener =

    OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorScriptFieldFocusListener(this)

        updatePieceKindsSpinnerAndLoadFirstScriptIfAny()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        updatePieceKindsSpinnerAndLoadFirstScriptIfAny()
    }

    private fun updatePieceKindsSpinnerAndLoadFirstScriptIfAny() {
        loadSpinnerTitles()
        loadScriptMatchingSpinnerSelectionOrDisableAndClearField()
        if (scriptsByPieceKind.isNotEmpty()) {

generator_editor_spinner_other_piece_global_constraint.setSelection(0)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorFragment {
            return OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorFragment()
        }

        fun deleteScriptAssociatedWithPieceKind(kind: PieceKind){
            scriptsByPieceKind.remove(kind)
        }

        val scriptsByPieceKind = mutableMapOf<PieceKind, String>()
    }

    private fun loadSpinnerTitles() {
        val pieceTypesStrings = resources.getStringArray(R.array.piece_type_spinner)
        val sideStrings = resources.getStringArray(R.array.player_computer_spinner)
        spinnerPiecesKindValues = 
PositionGeneratorValuesHolder.otherPiecesCount.map { it.pieceKind }
        val otherPiecesKinds = spinnerPiecesKindValues.map {
            "${pieceTypesStrings[it.pieceType.ordinal]} 
${sideStrings[it.side.ordinal]}"
        }.toTypedArray()

         val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, otherPiecesKinds)


          spinnerAdapter.
          setDropDownViewResource(
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        generator_editor_spinner_other_piece_global_constraint.adapter = spinnerAdapter

        setEmptyScriptsWheneverScriptMissingForASpinnerKey()
    }

    private fun setEmptyScriptsWheneverScriptMissingForASpinnerKey(){
        for (currentSpinnerKey in spinnerPiecesKindValues){
            if ( ! scriptsByPieceKind.containsKey(currentSpinnerKey) ) 
            {
                scriptsByPieceKind[currentSpinnerKey] = ""
            }
        }
    }

    fun loadScriptMatchingSpinnerSelectionOrDisableAndClearField(){
        if (spinnerPiecesKindValues.isEmpty()){

          generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
          text.clear()

         generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
         isEnabled = false
        }
        else {
            val selectedItemPosition = 
            generator_editor_spinner_other_piece_global_constraint.
                selectedItemPosition
            val selectedPieceKind = 
            spinnerPiecesKindValues[selectedItemPosition]
            val associatedScript = 
            scriptsByPieceKind[selectedPieceKind]

             generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
             isEnabled = true

              //----------------------------------------//
             // Here is the strange editText behaviour //
             //----------------------------------------//
             generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
             setText(associatedScript)

generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.postInvalidate()

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Logger.getLogger("loloof64").info("selected piece kind : $selectedPieceKind")
            Logger.getLogger("loloof64").info("associated script : $associatedScript")
            Logger.getLogger("loloof64").info("current script field value : ${generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.text}")
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }

    fun retainCurrentScript() {
        if (lastSpinnerSelectedItem != null){
            scriptsByPieceKind[lastSpinnerSelectedItem!!] = 
            generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.
            text.toString()
        }
    }

    fun removeScriptFieldFocus() {

generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.clearFocus()
    }

    fun updateLastSelectedItem() {
        val spinnerSelectedItemPosition = 
        generator_editor_spinner_other_piece_global_constraint.
        selectedItemPosition
        lastSpinnerSelectedItem =
                if (spinnerSelectedItemPosition == Spinner.INVALID_POSITION) null
                else spinnerPiecesKindValues[spinnerSelectedItemPosition]
    }

 }

class OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorSpinnerSelectionListener(parent: 
OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorFragment):
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        saveLastScriptAndSetToCurrent()
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        saveLastScriptAndSetToCurrent()
    }

    private fun saveLastScriptAndSetToCurrent(){
        parentRef.get()?.removeScriptFieldFocus()
        parentRef.get()?.updateLastSelectedItem()


        parentRef.get()?.
        loadScriptMatchingSpinnerSelectionOrDisableAndClearField()
    }

    private val parentRef = WeakReference(parent)
}

class OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorScriptFieldFocusListener(parent: 
OtherPiecesGlobalConstraintEditorFragment):
    View.OnFocusChangeListener
{
    override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
        if (!hasFocus){
            parentRef.get()?.retainCurrentScript()
        }
    }

    private val parentRef = WeakReference(parent)
}
```

Comment: Not sure how much Kotlin differs from Java, but sometimes, when the view is already "laid", you need to call view.invalidate() to update the view (or view.requestLayout()).

Comment: Thank you : I had tried `generator_editor_field_other_piece_global_constraint.postInvalidate()`in order to refresh the edittext, but without any effect. Maybe are you talking of the whole fragment view ? If so, what is the most efficient way to get reference to the layout view inside `loadScriptMatchingSpinnerSelectionOrDisableAndClearField()` the method where I need to update the editText ? Maybe I'll have to store a reference to my layout view in the class.

Comment: No, I think invalidating the desired view should be enough. Is it possible to call `invalidate()` on the view instead of `postInvalidate()` ?

Comment: invalidate() does not work either : when rotating emulator, it happens sometimes that the editText is not updated with the value I set with `editText.setText(newContent)`

Comment: You do not need to call `invalidate()`, edittext handles that on `setText` method. @loloof64 could you do one thing: Just comment out all code and just put a line for text set and check if it is still happening.

Comment: Yes, @chandil03, I can confirm that just setting a simple text in the fragment code makes the textView displaying content without problem. So the problem I am facing should have to be a matter of organisation.

Comment: @loloof64 yes, break the code in meaning full way. I can't read the code you have posted. Its not well structured and indented also.